# Popcorn was not injected in your file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, bower, popcornjs

While staging with grunt (grunt serve) I am getting:

```
Running "bower-install:app" (bower-install) task

popcornjs was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "app\bower_components\popcornjs" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.
```

I have added Popcorn.js to bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "NAME",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.2.6",
        .
        "popcornjs": "~1.3.0",
        .
        "angular-slugify": "1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
        "angular-scenario": "1.2.6"
    }
}
```

So as to my index.html:

```
<s_cript src="bower_components/popcornjs/popcorn.js"></script>
<s_cript src="bower_components/popcornjs/modules/player/popcorn.player.js"></script>
<s_cript src="bower_components/popcornjs/players/youtube/popcorn.youtube.js"></script>
<s_cript src="bower_components/popcornjs/plugins/code/popcorn.code.js"></script>
```

.'.'

Am I doing missing something? The other libraries working fine.

Comment: Is `popcorn.corn.js` the main popcorn file?

Comment: the _'s are not in the code.

Comment: @RUJordan popcorn.corn.js is not in the package.

Comment: @RUJordan I could not find popcorn.corn.js also in the zip ball downloaded directly from github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did a quick search on `popcornjs`. The repo you pull from when you say `bower install --save popcornjs` is https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/. That repo has a `bower.json` file, and that file has a `main` property in it. That property tells `grunt-bower-install` what file to inject in your HTML.

However, you are using version `~1.3.0`, which would pull down this: https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/tree/v1.3.0. That doesn't have a `bower.json`, thus `grunt-bower-install` has no way of knowing what file to include.

The solution is to manually include it in your HTML, or upgrade to the newer version that uses Bower properly.